# Using ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath

I'm trying to get the number of users for Chrome extensions

Here's an example one:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabby-cat/mefhakmgclhhfbdadeojlkbllmecialg?hl=en
```

Here's what I have in my Google Sheets cells:

A1:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabby-cat/mefhakmgclhhfbdadeojlkbllmecialg
```

A2:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/span[4]/text()")
```

But I keep getting `#N/A` in `A1` for some reason.

What a I doing wrong with the xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*")), 
 "where Col1 ends with '+ users' offset 5")
```

[image]